# Allow HTTP download in Android Studio

Tags: gradle

I am getting the following error in Android Studio:

```
> Could not download builder-4.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.2)
      > Could not get resource 'http://10.252.250.53:8081/lm/content/groups/public/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.1.2/builder-4.1.2.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'http://10.252.250.53:8081/lm/content/groups/public/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.1.2/builder-4.1.2.jar'.
            > Connect to 10.252.250.53:8081 [/10.252.250.53] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

I am able to download the file from that link in a browser. So I believe the issue is that Android Studio is not allowing HTTP download.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you download is quite outdated; this is version `7.0.2` meanwhile.

Either add a self-signed SSL certificate to `10.252.250.53:8081` + local machine and define a proxy:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=10.252.250.53
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8081
```

Or downgrade back to Gradle < 7.0 ...if you really want to use HTTP (which is merely dead already).